# C# TaskFactory not completing all iterations

Tags: c#, task, taskfactory

I am experiencing some oddities when using TaskFactory:

```
Task<int[]> parent = Task.Run(() =>
{
    int length = 100;
    var results = new int[length];
    TaskFactory tf = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent,
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

    // Create a list of tasks that we can wait for
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) // have to set -1 on length else out of bounds exception, huh?
    {
        taskList.Add(tf.StartNew(() => results[i] = i));
    }
    // Now wait for all tasks to complete
    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());

    return results;
});

parent.Wait();

var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith(
     parentTask =>
     {
        foreach (int i in parentTask.Result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    });

finalTask.Wait();

Console.ReadKey();
```

This gives an output similar to:

0
0
0
0
4
5
0
0
0
0
10
0
12
13
14
...
0
99

I do not understand why not all indices are non zero.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `WaitAll` instead of `await WhenAll`?

Comment: The `int[]` will default to having values of `0` which is `default(int)`. I think values are not being assigned to some indicies, rather than `0` being assigned by your code.

Comment: To extend @Dai's reasoning, do you need to be using `TaskFactory` at all?  Can you just use `async`/`await` and `Task.Run`?

Comment: Your comment, `// have to set -1 on length else out of bounds exception` is not accurate. You can go up to `i < length` (which means `i` will be `length - 1` on the last iteration)

Comment: @RufusL yes, the comment I made was that I had to set -1 so that an OutOfBounds exception didn't occur. This was happening because of the race condition pointed out by DarkFalcon

Comment: @Dai The reason is - I am following an example in a book, but I tend to modify the examples to learn more about them. I have used async/await before, but I still don't understand it fully, that chapter is yet to come.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you capture a variable with a lambda, this variable is placed into a compiler-generated object which is shared between the inner and outer scope. When you do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
{
    taskList.Add(tf.StartNew(() => results[i] = i));
}
```

The variable `i` is shared between both your loop and all the child tasks. There is only one `i` and it is being modified by the loop as the tasks are running. This is a race condition and will result in seemingly random data in the array every time, depending on how the tasks are scheduled.

The simplest way to solve this is to make an immutable variable scoped to the loop body:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) // You can now use length instead of length - 1
{
    int innerI = i;
    taskList.Add(tf.StartNew(() => results[innerI] = innerI));
}
```

There is now a separate `innerI` variable for every task, and it is assigned the value `i` exactly once and will not change.

---

Imagine the old code as transformed by the compiler into

```
class Generated1
{
    public int i;
}
var context = new Generated1(); // Exactly one copy of i
for (context.i = 0; context.i < length - 1; context.i++)
{
    taskList.Add(tf.StartNew(() => results[context.i] = context.i));
}
```

While the new code as transformed by the compiler becomes

```
class Generated2
{
    public int innerI;
}
for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
{
    var context = new Generated2(); // New copy of innerI for every loop iteration
    context.innerI = i;
    taskList.Add(tf.StartNew(() => results[context.innerI] = context.innerI));
}
```

---

Regarding why you had to use `length - 1`: Some of your tasks didn't run until the loop was complete. At that point, `i == length`, so you would get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` when trying to use `i` as an index into your array. When you fix the race condition with `i`, this can no longer happen.

Comment: Great explanation! I fully understand why this is occurring now and definitely one to remember for the future.